# Why is `toIdString` member of `Entity`?

Tags: xodus

My question is quite simple: Why is the method `toIdString` member of `jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.Entity` and not member of `jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.EntityId`?

Comment: upvote the answer if it helped you, if it solved your question please accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

`Entity#toIdString()` calls `EntityId#toString()`. For an `Entity e`, it's just a way to write `e.toIdString()` instead of `e.getId().toString()`.